# How to get the Laplace transform of $t \cdot f(t) \cdot e^t$

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there a formula to get the Laplace transform of $t \cdot f(t) \cdot e^t$ ?
I tried integration, but that got me nowhere, because I'm probably missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$f(t)e^t\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{F}(s-1)$$ and $$tf(t)\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\longleftrightarrow}-\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{F}(s)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $Imz>a$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [izt]te^{at} &=&\partial _{a}\int_{0}^{\infty
}dt\exp [izt]e^{at} \\
&=&\partial _{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [(iz+a)t]=\partial _{a}\frac{-1}{
iz+a}=\frac{1}{(iz+a)^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now set $a=1$. For the real Laplace transform replace $Imz$ by $-s$.
We see that the Laplace transform is not defined for all $s$.